# React Native: how can I implement topTabs within bottomTabs using react-native navigation

Tags: react-native

I want to create topTops within bottomTabs using react native navigation

please anyone help me

Comment: you should post your code and what you've already tried and people will gladly help any issues you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use react-native-tab-view for it
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view

```
import { TabView, TabBar, SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view';

const FirstRoute = () => (
  <View style={[styles.scene, { backgroundColor: '#ff4081' }]} />
);
const SecondRoute = () => (
  <View style={[styles.scene, { backgroundColor: '#673ab7' }]} />
);

export default class TabViewExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { key: 'first', title: 'First' },
      { key: 'second', title: 'Second' },
    ],
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TabView
        navigationState={this.state}
        renderScene={SceneMap({
          first: FirstRoute,
          second: SecondRoute,
        })}
        onIndexChange={index => this.setState({ index })}
        initialLayout={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

- navigationState -the current navigation state, should contain a routes array containing the list of tabs, and an index property representing the current tab

  - renderScene- callback which returns a React Element to use as the scene for a tab
  - onIndexChange-callback for when the current tab index changes, should update the navigation state

Or if you want to implement it yourself You can create top bar on the top of the screen and a container in the screen and on click on top bar item just replace the container component.

Comment: can I use with react native navigation library?

Comment: Yes you can. I'm using it too

Comment: @jenithajoe If this was what you were looking for please mark it as answer so it can help others coming to this post :)

Comment: @akil choundhary can you give me a sample code for this

Comment: Hey @jenithajoe, I have updated my answer with the sample code.Hope it helps. Let me know if you have some doubt